# Block Some UTXO

Tags: utxo

Is it possible to block some UTXO like PIVX, does is possible in bitcoin?
if yes then how and doesn't it reduce supply from total supply of bitcoin?

Let's Assume that account A got 5 bitcoin from Some random account and he spend 2 bitcoin. when he transfer 2 bitcoin he will send 5 btc and receive back 3 BTC as for my understanding. now if i want to make some change in code and block that UTXO of 3 BTC can this be done using code.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Could you please explain what "blocking UTXOs" means? This site's topic is Bitcoin, it seems that multiple prospective responders don't know what PIVX is.

Comment: Do you mean, "not create" with "block"? As in, how can you send a bitcoin transaction without creating a change output? What would your preferred outcome be: that when you use the 5 bitcoin, it creates the 2 BTC for the recipient, and the other 3 BTC are lost, that you find inputs that are exactly equal to the 2 BTC in the output and you just don't need to create change, or that the recipient gets tipped the remainder?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what PIVX is but you can send Bitcoin to an unspendable output (also known as burning). This does reduce how much Bitcoin can circulate, the initial supply steadily approaches 21 million but in theory any percentage of that can be burned.

Comment: No, i want to know about blocking some UTXO.

Comment: You'll have to explain what "blocking a UTXO" means, as that terminology does not exist in Bitcoin.